# C# print textbox with text

Tags: c#, console, cursor, ascii, offset

I'm trying to simulate a textbox style game pokemon. I read the sentences to a .txt file and when the character meets the edge of the frame of the textbox should wrap and keep writing. I'm trying with this method, but it does not work. I know you help?

```
public void DrawTextBox()
{
    //CONTROLLO INPUT
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);

    switch (key.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:
            isPress = true;
            break;
    }

    //STAMPO
    if (isPress ==true)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < Height; i++)
        {
           Console.CursorTop = Offset.y + i;

            for (j = 0; j < Width; j++)
            {
                Console.CursorLeft = Offset.x + j;

                if (Console.CursorLeft == Width - Offset.x)
                {
                    Console.CursorTop+=1;
                    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                }

                else
                    Console.Write(Dialog[i, j].Char);

                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make multiline property enabled for that textbox